# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could you explain how to find this limit?

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k+n}$

Comment: You could try to rewrite the sum to look like a Riemann sum.

Comment: What do you mean? Riemann sum is approximation for integral

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Could you explain the transformation that makes these two problems equivalent?  For now, I can't see how they're duplicates.

Comment: @anorton In the question here, let $m=k+n$. The sum becomes $\sum_{m=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. AH!  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Nice... :)  (And voted.)

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+1}\cdot \frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x+1}=\ln 2$.

Comment: Could you explain how did you replace sum with integral?

Comment: @EvanTello think in the reverse direction. What will the Riemann sum associated with the integral in RHS looks like? In this particular case, the LHS actually equal to the lower and the right Riemann sum associated with the RHS for the partition of $[0,1]$ into $n$ sub-intervals.

Comment: Yes, the RHS is the Darboux lower integral.